# Basic Knowledge about HTML Query Strings needed

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am new to the world of webdesign and already assigned myself with a very (at least for me) difficult task: I want to build a webpage, that sends a query string to the website of the German Railway (bahn.de) with the parameters I entered on my webpage.

My question now is, if there is a way to decipher the answer, the other webpage (bahn.de) is sending back in regard to my query string.

In my case there will be departure and arrival times, fares, line numbers, .... Is it possible to extract this information from the answer the bahn.de- page is sending?

Comment: Start by learning a serverside language, something like PHP with cURL is probably the easiest to grasp and is well documented.

Comment: The basic format of a query string is:

http:// bahn.de?param1=value1&param2=value2

Then, your serverside language will usually receive an array of parameters passed through the query string like so:

{ param1: value1, param2: value2 }

Hope this is enough to get you started!

Comment: @RUJordan - cross-origin policy, unless the OP actually owns bahn.de, which is doubtful, or the site has an API that will allow cross origin requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost you need to determine what type of data-encoding the website is returning. Is it `XML` or perhaps `JSON`? Both formats can be dealt with using a server-side language such as PHP, but the extraction process may differ slightly.

In order to continue along your learning path (which is great, by the way!) you'll need to find out a bit more about what kind of data object the website is sending back from your query. There are plenty of great resources at the other end of a Google search that can teach you how to handle that incoming data once you know which format it is in.

Comment: Ok, that does make sense to me. As one of the other answerers already pointed out, I do of course not own bahn.de and I am neither associated with it and its technical background. From my understanding, the only way to obtain the information you suggested I would need, would be asking the company directly about their web page. Is that right? Or is there any other way to gather this information?

Comment: Not necessarily - I just searched Google for 'bahn.de api' and this looks like an interesting read: http://www.programmableweb.com/api/deutsche-bahn-openbahn. I would probably start there. You will likely need to register and get an API key and then start writing your queries to retrieve the data they provide.

Comment: Ok, now that is great. I am quite embarrassed that I did not find that earlier. I am already experimenting with the Google Maps API and also send an email to Deutsche Bahn exactly about something like you suggested. Since I did get a negative answer from them, I did not pursue that approach. But thank you very much, that will help a lot!